# Is it safe to "Enable-MSDSMAutomaticClaim -BusType iSCSI" in an environment with multiple iSCSI-Targets?

Tags: storage, iscsi, mpio

I'm currently setting up a backup storage cluster (Acronis ACI) where I want to attach an iSCSI target to a Hyper-V host. The manual states to enable MPIO, which is fine.

The next step is to enable **MSDSM Automatic Claim** for iSCSI.

However, I can't find any information with Microsoft on how this will actually effect the environment. We currently have other, productive iSCSI targets that I certainly do not want to switch over to this Hyper-V host.

Does anyone of you know, if this concern is justified?

I'm working with this short manual: [ACI iSCSI manual for Hyper-V](https://dl.acronis.com/u/software-defined/html/AcronisCyberInfrastructure_4_5_users_guide_en-US/#accessing-iscsi-targets-from-microsoft-hyper-v.html)

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: It's as safe as automatically claiming all harddisks that are being inserted into a particular machine: safe until someone who isn't aware of that automatism does something unexpected.

Comment: Thank you Simon. I'm not sure I'm getting this right - would it not behave in the same way, if a new iSCSI target is "published" in the network? E.g. by creating a new one on a NAS?

Comment: that was more a general remark than an answer (which is why I posted it as a comment) that my main objection would not be a technical but an organizational one: you are creating a mechanism that would be unexpected to anyone new to your organization, so it would have to be part of the training manual for anyone who comes near these machines. Unless provisioning storage is part of your core business, I'd expect that the effort vs the reward of automating this step will not be worth it in employee time.